# How to make django-rules work in templates?

Tags: django, permissions, django-rules

When using [Django-Rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules), you can check permissions in views. But mine always returns false. Code in example below always displays 'bar', but must display 'foo':

```
  {% extends 'home/base.html' %}
  {% load rules %}
  {% has_perm 'anApp.can_access_something' user as can_access_something %}

  {% block content %}
      {% if can_access_something %}
          <p>foo</p>
      {% else %}
          <p>bar</p>
      {% endif %}
      ...
  {% endblock %}
```

My rules.py looks like this:

```
@rules.predicate
def testrule(user):
    return True

rules.add_perm('anApp.can_access_something', testrule)
```

So will always return true.

Answer (score 3):

The following line must be in a block:

```
{% has_perm 'anApp.can_access_something' user as can_access_something %}
```

This will correctly display 'foo':

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load rules %}

{% block content %}
    {% has_perm 'anApp.can_access_something' user as can_access_something %}
    {% if can_access_something %}
        <p>something</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>something else</p>
    {% endif %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```